# Changing the RenderTransformOrigin from code

Tags: c#, wpf, annotations

I need to change the RenderTransformOrigin property of some annotation objects, so that they always rotate around the center (y) of the other side (x).

So let's say the user clicks on the right hand side of the object, then the rotation point would be (0.0, 0.5), but if the user wishes to change the rotation from the other side of the item, then he can click on the left hand side of it, in which case the rotation point becomes (1.0, 0.5).

The problem: the reason I am asking for help is that whenever this happens, the item jumps on the screen. How much it moves, depends on the angle of the item (if it is not rotated at all, then it won't move at all). The angle itself does not change during the movement, only the position. (I realise that it is a bit difficult to understand the problem without images, but due to stackoverflow's rules, I am not allowed to attach images to make things easier.) So this only happens when selecting the other side (e.g. clicking on the left hand side after the right hand side), and the movement/jump depends on the angle (the larger the angle, the larger the jump).

What I would like to do is to change the mentioned property for the rotation to happen around the selected edge of the object, without the object keep jumping up and down when changing side.

Thank you for your help!

Edit [2015-03-10_12-17-21]

```
class XYZ  
{  
...  
private void RotateThumb_DragStarted(object sender, DragStartedEventArgs e) {
    m_rotateTransform = m_designerItem.RenderTransform as RotateTransform;

    if (m_rotateTransform == null) {
        m_designerItem.RenderTransform = new RotateTransform(0);
        m_rotateTransform = m_designerItem.RenderTransform as RotateTransform;
    }
    Point positionWithinAnnotation = Mouse.GetPosition(m_designerItem);
    var selectedThumb = GetThumbPosition(m_designerItem, positionWithinAnnotation);

    double relativeCenterX = ((selectedThumb == ThumbPosition.Left) ? (1.0D) : (0.0D));
    double relativeCenterY = 0.5D;

    m_designerItem.RenderTransformOrigin = new Point(relativeCenterX, relativeCenterY);
    m_transformOrigin = m_designerItem.RenderTransformOrigin;

    m_rotationPoint = m_designerItem.TranslatePoint(
        new Point(relativeCenterX * m_designerItem.ActualWidth,
                  relativeCenterY * m_designerItem.ActualHeight),
                  m_canvas);

    Point startPoint = Mouse.GetPosition(m_canvas);
    m_startVector = Point.Subtract(startPoint, m_rotationPoint);
}

private void handleRotate(DragDeltaEventArgs e) {
    Point currentPoint = Mouse.GetPosition(m_canvas);
    Vector deltaVector = Point.Subtract(currentPoint, m_rotationPoint);

    double angle = Vector.AngleBetween(m_startVector, deltaVector);
    m_rotateTransform.Angle += Math.Round(angle, 0);
    m_startVector = deltaVector;

    m_designerItem.InvalidateMeasure();
}

...
}
```

Comment: Without seeing any images, it seems obvious that the transformed shape somehow moves if you change the origin of an existing RotateTransform.

Comment: I forgot to add that changing RotateTransform's CenterX and CenterY properties have similar effect, even if the rotation, or the size of the object does not change at all. So by changing the rotation center, only its position changes. Any idea how to avoid this jump?

Comment: Of course it does. You may need to have a TransformGroup with two RotateTransforms or something like that. Hard to tell without having seen any of your code.

Comment: You are right; I pasted the relevant code!

Answer (score 0):

Without [a good, *minimal*, *complete* code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) it's difficult to know for sure what you need to do to fix the code.

That said, from the description it sounds to me like you should be using the `RotateTransform.CenterX` and `RotateTransform.CenterY` properties, instead of setting `RenderTransformOrigin`.

For example:

```
private void RotateThumb_DragStarted(object sender, DragStartedEventArgs e) {
    m_rotateTransform = m_designerItem.RenderTransform as RotateTransform;

    if (m_rotateTransform == null) {
        m_designerItem.RenderTransform = new RotateTransform();
        m_rotateTransform = m_designerItem.RenderTransform as RotateTransform;
    }
    Point positionWithinAnnotation = Mouse.GetPosition(m_designerItem);
    var selectedThumb = GetThumbPosition(m_designerItem, positionWithinAnnotation);

    double relativeCenterX = ((selectedThumb == ThumbPosition.Left) ? (1.0D) : (0.0D));
    double relativeCenterY = 0.5D;

    m_rotateTransform.CenterX = relativeCenterX;
    m_rotateTransform.CenterY = relativeCenterY;

    // Without a complete example, I'm not sure I know what this part is
    // supposed to be doing. I think it's fine, but maybe it needs to be
    // fixed too?
    m_rotationPoint = m_designerItem.TranslatePoint(
        new Point(relativeCenterX * m_designerItem.ActualWidth,
                  relativeCenterY * m_designerItem.ActualHeight),
                  m_canvas);

    Point startPoint = Mouse.GetPosition(m_canvas);
    m_startVector = Point.Subtract(startPoint, m_rotationPoint);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment! Unfortunately, as I mentioned it earlier, setting the CenterX and CenterY properties causes the same problem. 
By the way, the code is almost complete, minus stuff that is not relevant here. What I am trying to do is really simple: just trying to rotate an item from both left and right hand side, while changing the center point of the rotation to the opposite side.

Comment: @a14: Sorry... didn't see that note. It really should have been part of the question itself...comments are for _us_ to ask you for clarification; the actual clarification belongs in the question. As far as the code example goes, it's WPF so without XAML you're missing at least half the code. In any case "almost complete" != "complete". I really think `CenterX` and `CenterY` are what you need, but without a complete code example it's not clear why they didn't work for you.